# how to find guest account is enable or not

Tags: visual-c++

When I use registry key to get it always return error code=5 means ,access denied

how to decide that the guest account on the system Windows 7 is enabled or disabled using C++

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NetUserGetInfo with level 1 and check if USER_INFO_1.usri1_flags contains the UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE bit.

Comment: could you give me some workable sample code for windows 7 list guest accout is enable or disalbe if enable guest account name's list